Android Compose: Why is the data accessed by the detectability DragGesturesAfterLongPress callback not the latest data?
I customized a Modifier function:
fun Modifier.gridDragHandler(
    onDragStart: (key: Any) -> Boolean,
    ...
) = pointerInput(Unit) {
    detectDragGesturesAfterLongPress(
        onDragStart = { offset ->
            ...
            onDragStart(key)
            ...
        }
        ...
    )
}

Then use this function in LazyVerticalGrid:
@Composable
fun SelectableLazyVerticalGrid(
    itemList: List<SelectableItem>,   
    ...
) { 
    val list = remember { mutableStateListOf<SelectableItem>() }

    LaunchedEffect(itemList) {
        list.clear()
        list.addAll(itemList)
    }

    LazyVerticalGrid(
        modifier = Modifier.gridDragHandler(
            onDragStart = {
                println("itemList.size=${itemList.size}")
                println("list.size=${list.size}")
            },
            ...
        ),
        ...
    ) {
        ...
    }
}

I found that the itemList obtained in onDragStart is the data from a previous reorganization, not the latest data (the data in the list is correct and up-to-date).
Why can't itemList be directly used in the onDragStart callback?

Because pointerInput creates a closure and captures states and objects inside of it at the moment of it's initialization as remember, LaunchedEffect or DisposableEffect.
If the states or objects inside any of these closures are to change you should use pointerInput(key), remember(key), LaunchedEffect(key), DispoasableEffect(key).
In your case you most likely create new itemList but pointerInput retains previous instance of this list which you can easily check by logging objects inside and outside of pointerInput
use pointerInput(itemList) to reset it when list changes.
Value of MutableState inside Modifier.pointerInput doesn't change after remember keys updated
Switch Column between vertical scroll and dragging gesture in Jetpack Compose
Composable not recomposing on Android API 26 (Oreo) after changing the value of a MutableState

Thank you very much for your answer, which has taught me more.
